# updating dictionaries in python from list of booleans

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, iteration

I have an empty dictionary I want to add to. My solution works but I want to keep adding for each iteration in a dataset. The outcome is only showing one key:value pair. Is there a way to do this?
My list (results) contains boolean values.
It would be even better to have two nested dictionaries of true and false.

```
my_dict = {}

results = [True, True, False, True]

for result in results:

    my_dict.update('result': result[-1])
```

Comment: please [edit] and share the expected result

Comment: you re-use the key `"result"` each iteration, so it's replaced each time ..which could lead to a dict with only one key (the same key is set 4 times) .. however, this doesn't work as-written (`SyntaxError`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using nested dictionaries:

```
    fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape']
    results = [True, False, True, False]
    
    nested_dict = {
        'true': {},
        'false': {}
    }
    
   for fruit, value in zip(fruits, results):
        if value:
            nested_dict['true'][fruit] = "Ripe"
        else:
            nested_dict['false'][fruit] = "Unripe"
    
    
    print(nested_dict)
```